# Flutter FilterChip is not removed with origined, and have a side effect

Tags: flutter

it's dummy data and the new variable list will be put on a filter

```
List<Map<String, dynamic>> dummyData = [
  {'text': 'Charming', 'isSelected': false},
  {'text': 'Glamorous', 'isSelected': false},
  {'text': 'Chic', 'isSelected': false},
  {'text': 'Enchanting', 'isSelected': false},
  {'text': 'Bold', 'isSelected': false},
  {'text': 'Feminine', 'isSelected': false},
  {'text': 'Comfortable', 'isSelected': false},
  {'text': 'Mature', 'isSelected': false},
  {'text': 'Trendy', 'isSelected': false},
  {'text': 'Lively', 'isSelected': false},
  {'text': 'Innocent', 'isSelected': false},
  {'text': 'Cute', 'isSelected': false},
  {'text': 'Unique', 'isSelected': false},
  {'text': 'Sexy', 'isSelected': false},
  {'text': 'Challenging', 'isSelected': false},
  {'text': 'Tranquil', 'isSelected': false},
  {'text': 'Free-spirited', 'isSelected': false},
  {'text': 'Cricket', 'isSelected': false},
];

  List<Map<String, dynamic>> filters = [];

... 

Wrap(
                            spacing: 10.0, // Chip 간의 가로 간격
                            runSpacing: 2.0, // Chip 행 간의 세로 간격
                            children: List.generate(17, (index) {
                              // 10개의 Chip을 생성
                              return FilterChip(
                                showCheckmark: false,
                                padding: EdgeInsets.all(2),
                                backgroundColor: dummyData[index]['isSelected'] ? Colors.black : Colors.white,
                                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                    side: BorderSide(
                                      color: Color(0xFF989394).withOpacity(0.33), 
                                      width: 1.0, // 선의 두께
                                    ),
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)
                                ),
                                label: Text(dummyData[index]['text'],style: TextStyle(
                                color: dummyData[index]['isSelected'] ? Colors.white : Colors.black,
                              ),),
                                selected: dummyData[index]['isSelected'],
                                onSelected: (bool value) {
                                  setState(() {
                                    if(value && filters.length < 5 ) {
                                      dummyData[index]['isSelected'] = value;
                                      filters.add(dummyData[index]);
                                    } else if (!value) {
                                      dummyData[index]['isSelected'] = value;
                                      filters.remove(dummyData[index]);
                                    }
                                  });
                                },
                              );
                            }),
                          ),
                          Spacer(),
                        Wrap(
                          spacing: 10,
                          runSpacing: 2,
                          children: List.generate(filters.length, (index) {
                            final filteredItem = filters[index];
                            print('Filtered Item: $filteredItem');
                            return FilterChip(
                                showCheckmark: false,
                              padding: EdgeInsets.all(2),
                              label: Text(filteredItem['text']),
                              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                side: BorderSide(
                                  color: Color(0xFF989394).withOpacity(0.33),
                                  width: 1.0,
                                ),
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                              ),
                              selected: dummyData[index]['isSelected'],
                              onSelected: (bool selected) {
                                print('Selected: $selected');
                                setState(() {
                                  dummyData[index]['isSelected'] = selected;
                                  if (selected) {
                                    // 이미 선택된 아이템이면 제거
                                    if (filters.contains(filteredItem)) {
                                      filters.remove(filteredItem);
                                      print('Removed Filter: $filteredItem');
                                    }
                                  }
                                });
                              },
                            );
                          }),
                        ),
```

it's my code. After selecting a chip, a new chip with the same content is created. I want to click on the created chip again and reflect 'isSelected' as false. However, in the current logic, filtered chips are deleted, but the above chips are not updated. Moreover, there are issues with side effects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the second `FilterChip` replace

```
selected: dummyData[index]['isSelected'],
```

with

```
selected: filters[index]['isSelected'],
```

and

```
dummyData[index]['isSelected'] = selected;
if (selected) {
```

with

```
filters[index]['isSelected'] = selected;
if (!selected) {
```